# Почему я не могу в input вывести value тэга select?

Tags: javascript, html

Мне надо, чтоб value, выбранного option, выводилось в input. Почему я не могу этого сделать?

```js
const s18 = document.querySelector('.s-18');
const i18 = document.querySelector('.i-18');
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

function f18() {
    i18.innerHTML = (s18.value);
}
document.querySelector('.s-18').onchange = f18;
```

```html
<select class="s-18">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="five">5</option>
</select>

<div>
  Input: <input type="text" class="i-18">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в типе [элемента](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604299/what-is-innerhtml-on-input-elements)

> **value** applies only to objects that have the value attribute (normally,
> form controls).
>
> **innerHtml** applies to every object that can contain HTML (divs, spans,
> but many other and also form controls).

если в кратце - если элемент содержит атрибут **value** используйте его, иначе **innerHtml**

```js
const s18 = document.querySelector('.s-18');
const i18 = document.querySelector('.i-18');
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

function f18() {
    i18.value = (s18.value);
}
document.querySelector('.s-18').onchange = f18;
```

```html
<select class="s-18">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="five">5</option>
</select>

<div>
  Input: <input type="text" class="i-18">
</div>
```

Ваш вариант работает для других элементов

```js
const s18 = document.querySelector('.s-18');
const i18 = document.querySelector('.i-18');
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

function f18() {
    i18.innerHTML = (s18.value);
}
document.querySelector('.s-18').onchange = f18;
```

```html
<select class="s-18">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="five">5</option>
</select>

<div>
  Input: <div class="i-18"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут скорее сказывается то, что вставить что-то с помощью `innerHTML` можно только в элемент, который имеет как открывающий, так и [закрывающий тэг](https://puzzleweb.ru/javascript/element_innerhtml.php). Так как с помощью `innerHTML` мы вставляем что-то внутрь самого html-элемента... а тут в самом деле немного другой случай

Comment: @Eva если посмотрите то увидите пример с другим тегом

Comment: `<div class="i-18"/>` - вообще div [должен](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) иметь открывающий и закрывающий тэги, и тогда вполне логично, что innerHTML употребляется и работает с этим элементом.

Comment: Можно подправить это не проблема. Основная идея понять как работает