# Помогите решить задачу, пожалуйста (js)

Tags: javascript, html

я недавно начал изучать Js, и в курсе попалась следующая задача:

Дан select s-110. По изменению состояния select (событие onchange) выведите value выбранного option в out-11.

я не понимаю что такое изминение состояния onchange

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему я не могу в input вывести value тэга select?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256196/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2-input-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-value-%d1%82%d1%8d%d0%b3%d0%b0-select)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const $element = document.getElementById('select');
const $input = document.getElementById("input");

$element.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const currentValue = this.value
  console.log('Текущее выбранное значени =', currentValue)
  $input.value = currentValue
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<input id="input" type="text" value="">
```